# Best solution for dual monitor using chrome book and desktop computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop, switch, chromebook, kvm-switch

I'm looking for the best solution for a home working setup that comprises of a desktop computer and a Chromebook. I would like to share dual monitors and a single keyboard and mouse between the 2 devices. It's not important for the 2 devices to run simultaneously I just want each device to use the monitors and peripherals independently when fired up without having to switch cables etc.

I've looked at dual monitor KVM appliances such as made by TESmart but these seem overkill for my requirements.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be most helpful.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: If its just the monitors, there's really cheap/simple HDMI switchers - not sure of a good software mouse/keyboard option that does chromebooks but that would handle that end well

Comment: So technically a HDMI/USB switcher?